# Interpolate a Numpy array without using insert

Tags: python, numpy, memory-efficient

So I am trying to do some interpolation, I just would like to know if it is possible for the code I am using to be more efficient.

So the problem is this. I have an array of values that contains data from a lot of different station. It has dimensions N x 85, N could be different depending on the region in the world.

As of right now the time spacing between them is not even. The columns 0:51 have a 3 hour timedelta between them and then columns 52:84 have a six hour timedelta in between them. I just want to do a simple linear interpolation in between them to make it so that all of the rows will have a 3 hour spacing between them, so basically just the calculate the means between the rows 52:84 and insert them in the correct place.

Here is a quick code sample of a small scale example, which is what I have currently been doing but is not so efficient (the insert function is what I would like to avoid).

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.nan)

array = np.random.rand(5, 10) * 10
print(array)

interpolation_array = np.empty((5, 4))

for i, j in enumerate(list(range(5, 9))):
    interpolation_array[:, i] = np.mean(array[:, j:(j+2)], axis=1)
print(interpolation_array)

# This is the line that is not memory efficient
final_array = np.insert(array, list(range(6, 10)), interpolation_array, axis=1)

print(final_array)
```

Comment: If you are doing just one insert, I don't see a problem.  You can't grow the original array inplace.

Comment: If you don't want to use `insert`, you can create a `final_array` that is large enough, and copy values from `array` and `interpolation_array` to the necessary slots.

Comment: @hdpaulj That's what I was thinking, I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something built in that could give me speed ups. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as suggested by @hpaulj, I made an implementation using Numba (LLVM compiler is faster than Numpy) that created a large matrix to write all of the values to, and then used parallel loops to fill it and to do the simple linear interpolations. Here is the code that I used.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_approach(array, c_start):  # c_start is column to start interpolating in (zero indexed)
    num_rows = array.shape[0]
    num_cols = array.shape[1]
    num_interp_columns = num_cols - 1 - c_start

    final_array = np.empty((num_rows, num_cols + num_interp_columns))

    # Populate the Portion That is not interpolated
    for i in prange(num_rows):
        for j in range(c_start + 1):
            final_array[i, j] = array[i, j]

    z = 1
    for j in prange(c_start + 2, num_cols + num_interp_columns, 2):
        for i in range(num_rows):
            final_array[i, j] = array[i, j - z]
        z += 1

    # Interpolate
    for j in prange(c_start + 1, num_cols + num_interp_columns - 1, 2):
        for i in range(num_rows):
            final_array[i, j] = (final_array[i, j - 1] + final_array[i, j + 1]) / 2

    return final_array
```

This gave me about a 4 times speedup, which is relatively significant since this particular section of code is run frequently.

Benchmarks:

```
%timeit numpy_approach(test_array)

100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop

%timeit numba_approach(test_array, 47)

1000 loops, best of 3: 446 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to do this is by using a proper linear interpolation, for instance [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). The corresponding time of each value have to be defined explicitly. This allows the generalization to any time spacing between the values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

times = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36]
values = np.random.rand(len(times))

times_regular = np.arange(0, times[-1]+1, 3)

values_regular = np.interp(times_regular, times, values)

plt.plot(times_regular, values_regular, 's', label='evently spaced');
plt.plot(times, values, 'd-', label='measure');
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('value'); plt.legend();
```

---

An array based solution, since only the mid-point is wanted, could be:

```
data_every6hr = np.array([[7, 5, 6, 9, 8, 5],
                          [7, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9],
                          [5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 8],
                          [5, 9, 8, 5, 7, 6]], dtype=float)

# Perform the interpolation for every line
intermediate_values = (data_every6hr[:, 1:] + data_every6hr[:, :-1])/2

# Insert the interpolated values before each column:
data_every3hr = np.insert(data_every6hr,
                          range(1, data_every6hr.shape[1]),
                          intermediate_values,
                          axis=1)

print(data_every3hr)
#array([[7. , 6. , 5. , 5.5, 6. , 7.5, 9. , 8.5, 8. , 6.5, 5. ],
#       [7. , 8. , 9. , 7.5, 6. , 5.5, 5. , 5.5, 6. , 7.5, 9. ],
#       [5. , 5.5, 6. , 6.5, 7. , 8. , 9. , 8.5, 8. , 8. , 8. ],
#       [5. , 7. , 9. , 8.5, 8. , 6.5, 5. , 6. , 7. , 6.5, 6. ]])
```

`data_every6hr` is only the part of the input array where the data are 6 hour separated.

Comment: Did you run benchmarks? If this implementation is quicker than that is fine but I need it to be memory efficient and quick. That is the reason I just did a simple linear interpolation using averages. But generally, yes, I would agree that it is better to use the built in interpolation tool that is provided by numpy.

Comment: Also @xdze2 can this method interpolate rows in a 2D array?

Comment: @Wade I added another solution which is I think closer to your code. How large is `N` in your application?

Comment: N is typically around 1500, sorry I forgot to mention that in the original question. It could be larger I believe.